# Works in Shell but not script

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Using Flask, SQLAlchemy and SQLite3.

Long story short; when I run the server enter my data on the webpage and submit it the changes aren't reflected in the database, although I get no errors.  HOWEVER when I run the shell / interpreter and input my model, db object then enter my data the changes ARE in the database.  Here is a snippet of the code I am referring to.  I must be missing something simple.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///core1.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Motor(db.Model):

__tablename__ = 'Motor'

asset_tag = db.Column('Asset Tag', db.String(100), unique=True, primary_key = True)
horsepower = db.Column('Horsepower', db.Integer)

def __init__(self, asset_tag, horsepower):
    self.asset_tag = asset_tag
    self.horsepower = horsepower

@app.route('/submit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        asset_input = request.form['asset_tag']
        horsepower_input = request.form['horsepower']
        pass_to_db = Motor(asset_input, horsepower_input)
        db.session.add(pass_to_db)
        db.session.commit
    return render_template('submit.html', error=error)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug = True)
```

To test if something was wrong with my forms logic I wrote a script that just took raw inputs and again I got the same results. Raw user variable entries only showed up if run within shell, however when I ran the script nothing was added.  This was the test I used below;

```
def testentry():
    asset_input = raw_input("Enter asset tag: ")
    horsepower_input = raw_input("Enter the horsepower: ")
    pass_to_db = Motor(asset_input, horsepower_input)
    db.session.add(pass_to_db)
    db.session.commit

testentry
```

Comment: Initial thoughts are either permission OR path issues. Did you check both of these?

Comment: Well I just ran the script as sudo and no luck there either.  What should I be looking for in regards to the path?

Comment: I'm setting up a new VM to test that though @RyanO'Donnell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't closing my commit() Method at the end.  The last bit of code looks like this now and works;

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit():
error = None
if request.method == 'POST':
    asset_input = request.form['asset_tag']
    horsepower_input = request.form['horsepower']
    pass_to_db = Motor(asset_input, horsepower_input)
    db.session.add(pass_to_db)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('submit.html', error=error)
```